MBS IO vs Short Treasury Futures?
Assuming that the yield curve is upward sloping, what is a better way to achieve negative duration exposure - buying an interest only (IO) strip given it's highly positive carry or shorting US treasury futures? What provides better risk/reward in terms of carry especially?
